# Popover with id data in list (React, Material UI)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a table list with `first name`, `last name` and `email`. The email section is a clickable popover `SimplePopper`:

```
<TableCell>{list.first_name}</TableCell>
<TableCell>{list.last_name}</TableCell>
<TableCell><SimplePopper /></TableCell>
```

I'd like the popover to only display the email related to the id at the row level, but at the moment it displays all emails. Is there a simple way to pass something on `<SimplePopper />` so I see the related emails to each first and last name?

`SimplePopper` calls this function:

```
function PostPopover() {
    return (
        <div>
            {PostData.map((list, index)=>{
                return <div>
                    {list.email} 
                    </div>
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Edit: added SimplePopper code

```
function PostPopover() {
    return (
        <div>
            {PostData.map((list, index)=>{
                return <div>
                    {list.email} 
                    </div>
            })}
        </div>
    )
}


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    border: '1px solid',
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
}));

export default function SimplePopper() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(anchorEl ? null : event.currentTarget);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? 'simple-popper' : undefined;

  return (
    <div>
      <button aria-describedby={id} type="button" onClick={handleClick} color="primary">
        Show email clicking here
      </button>
      <Popper id={id} open={open} anchorEl={anchorEl}>
        <div className={classes.paper}><PostPopover />.</div>
      </Popper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Edit: PostData structure (1,000 fake records)

```
[{"id":1,
"first_name":"Geraldine",
"last_name":"Graal",
"email":"ggraal0@indiegogo.com"},
{"id":2,
"first_name":"Farris",
"last_name":"Sowten",
"email":"fsowten1@blogger.com"}]
```

Comment: it looks like, you passing Postdata which is an array, you can pass id to SimplePoper and you can filter the email from PostData.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's a long shot for me...

Comment: if you can add your SimplePopper component code, maybe I can come up with the code.

Comment: @sam that's the code added!

Comment: Can you please add your PostData structure?, Why do we need to loop through PostData to get the email?

Comment: If you're already iterating over the list to render the table rows, you should be able to just pass `list.email` as a prop into `SimplePopover` (and ultimately in `PostPopover`).

Comment: @ericgio I know, I am just trying to learn different things on React.

Comment: @Sam that´s added! I know I can just add {list.email} in <TableCell>, but having a popover has to do with UX stuff.

Comment: @AntonioAndrés: You asked a straightforward question and my comment addresses it. If you're looking for a specific answer, please clarify that in your question so others can help you.

Comment: @ericgio Thanks and sorry for my lack of knowledge. I am trying to figure out how to to do that.